Least invasive way to open a file without disturbing any other process using it?
I have a .NET6 application running on Windows that has to open and read a bunch of files. I want this to be as non-invasive as possible, me opening these files should never interfere with any other process reading, writing or deleting them. If another process does something that would conflict with my application, that process should win and my application should get the error.
I'm opening the files in the following way:
using var stream = file.Open(
   FileMode.Open,
   FileAccess.Read,
   FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete
);


This still seems to interfere with someone trying to delete these files when they are opened by my application.
Is it possible to read files on Windows in a way that doesn't interfere with anything other processes do with them?

The Windows documentation contains the following statements:
_The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that has other handles open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file (FILE_SHARE_DELETE must have been specified when other handles were opened).
The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed. Subsequent calls to CreateFile to open the file fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED._

I do not believe it's possible to open a file in a way that still allows other applications to delete it while you have it open. There are other restrictions as well.

On windows there is "Volume Shadow Copy" that is intended to allow backups from a single point in time, regardless of other processes using the files. Not sure if it is applicable, but you might want to check it out.
